# SSH timing out to a Gentoo AMI (Amazon EC2)

Tags: amazon-ec2, gentoo

I created a new instance of a Gentoo AMI (`Gentoo_64-bit-EBS-2012-03-02-07-39-15 (ami-6ab26f03)`).

Both Status Checks passed (both system and instance reachability passed).

I know the Key Pair Name is correct, because I used the same keys to connect to the default Amazon Linux (`amzn-ami-2011.09.2.x86_64-ebs (ami-1b814f72)`).

This is what the verbose mode of SSH says (replaced the IP info with 99.99.99.99)

```
hobbes3@hobbes3:~/.ssh$ ssh -v root@ec2-99-99-99-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/hobbes3/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-99-99-99-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com [99.99.99.99] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 99.99.99.99 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host ec2-99-99-99-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

Is there something else I can do to see what the problem could be? Because operation timing out is a very vague output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a firewall issue to me.  Can you verify that port 22 is open on your instance?  I have never used Amazon as a provider, but I found some instructions for [creating a security group](http://support.rightscale.com/03-Tutorials/02-AWS/02-Website_Edition/2._Deployment_Setup/1._Create_a_Security_Group) which sounds like the right direction.

Comment: +1 -- make sure you have a security group that permits SSH to your hosts. I ran into this problem when I setup my first host.

Comment: @JeffFerland - Glad someone with some Amazon experience could back me up.  :)

Comment: Thank for the response. Your comment seems to have solved the problem. I created another instance with a security group from "default" to "quicklaunch-1", which was also the same security group that the Amazon Linux used. But now it's asking for the root password, which I have no clue what it is...

Comment: @hobbes3 - Like I said, I haven't used Amazon as a provider, so I'm not sure how that process works (did they e-mail you a password? did you set one during setup?).  You could either check with Amazon or post another question any maybe someone with some EC2 experience can help you out.

Comment: I was suppose to log in as `ec2-user`, not as `root` first. Thanks for the response!